# Trouble understanding the Debian bug reporting system

Tags: debian, bugs

I am currently experiencing [this bug](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=520285), except that I'm using the Wheezy/testing netinstaller. Strangely, I used the netinst .iso a few months ago, and everything was fine. So it almost seems as if the same bug keeps creeping back into the system. That said, I have a very hard time understanding the format of the bug reporting system. What does 'archived' mean? Does that mean it was fixed? And what should I do to report my bug, given that it's with the most recent version of the installer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Bug is archived. No further changes may be made.

“Archived” means that the bug has been resolved in some way (fixed, or closed as invalid). An archived bug won't change at all. If you see no non-archived bug that corresponds to your issue, report a new one.